# I got merge error for take rgb images channel

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing

I try to change Python to C++.

Here is my first variable defined like this:

```
x = np.ones((h,w,4),dtype=np.uint8)*255
```

I want to equalize third channel to another variable like this:

```
x[:,:,3] = y
```

I am using OpenCV. I coded a little bit on C++ like this:

```
cv::Mat x;
x = cv::Mat::ones(cv::Size(h, w), CV_32FC1)*255;
cv::Mat channel[3];
cv::split(x, channel);
channel[0] = cv::Mat::zeros(x.rows, x.cols, CV_32FC1);
cv::merge(channel,3,x);
```

I got this error when i run code:
**merge.dispatch.cpp:129: error: (-215:Assertion failed) mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth in function 'merge'**

How can I fix this?

Comment: Change type of `x` to be 3 channels, `CV_32FC3`.

Comment: Replace `x = cv::Mat::ones(cv::Size(h, w), CV_32FC1)*255;` with `x = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(h, w), CV_32FC3) + cv::Scalar(255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f);`.